# How to force delete action button to call delete controller in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid delete action button is used to delete row.
This button click calls Edit method, it looks like it uses editurl parameter.
How to force it to call Delete method like Delete toolbar button calls ?

```
$(function () {
            var grid = $("#grid");
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: '/GetData',
                colModel: [{ 
                "formatter":"actions",
                "formatoptions":{"keys":true,"delbutton":true,
                ...
               }}],
                editurl: '/Edit',
            });

          grid.navGrid("#grid_toppager", null,null,null, { url: '/Delete' } );
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include `delOptions` option in the `formatoptions`:

```
formatter: "actions",
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    delbutton: true,
    delOptions: {
        url: "/Delete"
    }
}
```

Inside of `delOptions` you can use any from the [properties](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) and any [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) of the [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) method.